# Set iskeyword selectively

Tags: search, vim, yank

Often I need to search large xml mode files for the next occurrence of the word under the cursor but preferably not if it's a tag the closing tag

In the below example # is where the cursor is. Using `*` or `#` with iskeyword not including `>` or `<` will move between `<Dealid>` and `</Dealid>`.

```
<Deali#d>4444</Dealid>
... 50 lines
<Dealid>6666</Dealid>
... n lines
<Dealid>5643</Dealid>
```

I tried `:set iskeyword+=<` which worked fine for moving to the next match but it changed `vey` to include the `<` of the closing tag so moving to the start of `6666`, for eg, and typing `vey` will yank `6666<` rather than `6666`.

Anyway of getting the best of both words or limit the `iskeyword+=<` to the `*` and `#` operators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
nnoremap * :set iskeyword+=<<CR>*:set iskeyword-=<<CR>
nnoremap # :set iskeyword+=<<CR>#:set iskeyword-=<<CR>
```

It sets changes `iskeyword` before executing `*` or `#` and then resets it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing `'iskeyword'` maybe use a [visual star search](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search). This will allow you to visually select the text and then hit `*`. e.g. `va<*`

If you don't want to use a plugin you can put the following mapping in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
xnoremap * y/\V<c-r>=escape(@", '\')<cr><cr>
```

Note: this mapping clobbers the unnamed register so it would probably be best to use a [more advanced mapping](http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2008/07/vim-pr0n-visual-search-mappings.html) or a [plugin](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search).

Comment: I had tried a visual search using * previously and didn't like it but thanks for the suggestion. I'll certainly look at the plugin