# Vim: match qualified identifier under cursor

Tags: vim, match

How can I match fully qualified identifier under cursor?

I'm searching for a way to collect from a script something like `::std::unique_ptr` or `MyNamespace::MyClassName` depending where cursor is located when editing line `::std::unique_ptr<MyNamespace::MyClassName>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most flexible ways to find anything arbitrary under/before/after cursor is to use the VIM's regexp `\%#` token which match current cursor position. For example:

```
[a-z]*\%#[a-z]*
```

(I use here `[a-z]` only as an example.)

The regexp would match letters before and after the cursor.

Since the `*` matches `0 or more`, that would also match empty space, which is sometimes undesirable. To solve the problem I have used the *brute* *force*:

```
[a-z]*\%#[a-z]\+\|[a-z]\+\%#[a-z]*
```

Though the approach is more verbose than the `expand(<cword>)`, it has the advantage of being independent of the `iskeyword` option.

Answer (score 0):

Built into Vim are only `:echo expand('<cWORD>')` (matching anything whitespace-delimited) and `:echo expand('<cword>')` (probably matching too little). You could fix the latter by including more characters in `'iskeyword'`, but that affects movement and maybe even syntax highlighting.

Alternatively, you could use a function from my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) to implement your own extractor, based on a regular expression:

```
if search('[:_[:alnum:]]\+', 'bcW') | echo ingo#text#frompattern#GetHere('[:_[:alnum:]]\+') | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add `:` in `iskeyword`, like

```
nnoremap * :set iskeyword+=:<CR>*:set iskeyword-=:<CR>
nnoremap # :set iskeyword+=:<CR>#:set iskeyword-=:<CR>
```

Put this in your `vimrc` file, then when trigger `#/*`, it will also include `::` as part of a word. One pitfall is that it will consider `True:False` as a single word.

See also [Set iskeyword selectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007655/set-iskeyword-selectively)